# "res" in BitmapDrawable(Resource res, Bitmap bitmap), can we use Resources.getSystem() ? or can only use context.getResource()?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-resources

In source code of android

```
/**
 * Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
 * system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for
 * the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
 * on orientation, etc).
 */
public static Resources getSystem() {
    synchronized (sSync) {
        Resources ret = mSystem;
        if (ret == null) {
            ret = new Resources();
            mSystem = ret;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

From the code we can get that getSystem() return a resource is not configured for the current screen, So in BitmapDrawable(Resource res, Bitmap bitmap),is it we can only use context.getResource() ?

Comment: "no application resources"

Comment: so, I can't use that method to access the resource? But when I input "BitMapDrawable() Resource.getSystem()" in google, I can get a lots of result that  write the code in this way, So they are wrong ?

Comment: no. you cannot. You have to use the `getResources()` from your application `Context`.